# Convert decimal number to hexadecimal in perl in specific format

Tags: perl

**initialize a scalar variable with an integer value**

```
my $dec = 1211;
print "Hexadecimal number: ", uc(sprintf("%x\n", $dec)), "\n";
```

**displays `4BB`**

But how can i get the output in `000004BB` ormat.

Comment: `$dec` is a misnomer. *Decimal* (and hexadecimal) are ways to represent a number using text, a string. `$dec` does not contain a string. It contains a 2's complement *number*. `$num` makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Use a length specifier with leading zeroes:

```
sprintf('%08X', $dec)
```

Also, you don't need to use the `uc()` function: just use the `%X` (capital-X) format character.

To print the heading as well:

```
printf "Hexadecimal number: %08X\n", $dec
```